# C++ multiple threads using std::locale to separate by thousands- weird results

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to thousand-separate numbers (e.g. 6,000,000). After doing some research I wrote the below method:

```
template<class TYPE>
std::string thousands(const TYPE num)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss.imbue(std::locale(""));
    ss << value;
    return ss.str();
}
```

To be used like:

`std::cout << thousands<uint64_t>(value) << std::endl;`

Initially this seemed to work in a single threaded environment. However, I have started using multiple threads and even though I am passing in a stack variable (not shared across threads) the value of `num` was getting incremented by the formatting. When I removed the formatting the incrementing stopped.

Is there some oddity with using the above technique to format strings from multiple threads?

After some more testing, does `imbue` cache anything? The problem seems to trigger when both threads call it at the same time.

UPDATE

Whilst testing I was able to safely conclude the above code is definitely causing problems and some sort of caching/static is occurring. When I replace the above with `return std::to_string(num)` the problem never occurs. I revert back to the above code, problem occurs every time. I use one thread- no problem. Two threads calling imbue(), problem reappears.

Using Clang compiler, CentOS 7 OS.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a minimal program?  [mcve] -- the thing is, if you are engaging in UB, unrelated code can add or remove symptoms.  And threading code is hard.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Not really, I'm receiving data from two streams, two threads and the data dictates the ordering which I call my above method. I'm just asking in case someone says "yes that's not thread safe"

Comment: The function as is should be thread safe.  `imbue` doesn't say that it isn't thread safe and `ss` is local to the function so it is not like that is shared.  We need a [mre] to be able to actually help you figure it out.

Comment: The thing is, I've been exposed to locale-related global state bugs.  I don't know if you are seeing some code leaking into global state, timing changes caused by locks in the above code, race conditions around using the default locale, UB being exposed by accident, etc.  With a huge field of possible ways your code can experience your symptoms it isn't practical to drill down into any and determine if they are likely or not.  If you could reproduce the problem in a [mcve] things look much more practical to look into.

Comment: Maybe you can have a static std:: thread_local std::locale variable. Like that std::locale will be defined once for each thread without interfering.

Comment: Apologies I haven't had time to try and create a smaller example. However, whilst testing I was able to safely conclude the above code is definitely causing problems and some sort of caching/static is occurring. I replace the above with std::to_string() and the problem never occurs. I revert back to the above code, problem occurs every time. I use one thread- no problem. Two threads calling imbue(), problem!